# Python3 working with csv files in tar files

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, tar

I am trying to work with csv files contained in a tar.gz file and I am having issues passing the correct data/object through to the csv module.

Say I have a tar.gz file with a number of csv files formated as follows.

```
1079,SAMPLE_A,GROUP,001,,2017/02/15 22:57:30
1041,SAMPLE_B,GROUP,023,,2017/02/15 22:57:26
1077,SAMPLE_C,GROUP,005,,2017/02/15 22:57:31
1079,SAMPLE_A,GROUP,128,,2017/02/15 22:57:38
```

I want to be able to access each csv file in memory without extracting each file from the tar file and writing them to disk.
For example:

```
import tarfile
import csv

tar = tarfile.open("tar-file.tar.gz")

for member in tar.getmembers():
    f = tar.extractfile(member).read()
    content = csv.reader(f)
    for row in content:
        print(row)
tar.close()
```

This produces the following error.

```
    for row in content:
_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not int (did you open the file in text mode?)
```

I have also tried parsing f as a string as described in the csv module documentation.

```
content = csv.reader([f])
```

The above produces the same error.

I have tried parsing the file object f as ascii.

```
f = tar.extractfile(member).read().decode('ascii')
```

but this iterates each csv element instead of iterating rows containing lists of elements.

```
['1']
['0']
['7']
['9']
['', '']
['S']
['A']
['M']
['P']
['L']
['E']
['_']
['A']
['', '']
['G']
['R']
```

snip...

```
['2']
['0']
['1']
['7']
['/']
['0']
['2']
['/']
['1']
['5']
[' ']
['2']
['2']
[':']
['5']
['7']
[':']
['3']
['8']
[]
[]
```

Trying to both parse f as ascii and read it as a string

```
f = tar.extractfile(member).read().decode('ascii')
content = csv.reader([f])
```

produces the following output

```
    for row in content:
_csv.Error: new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?
```

To demonstrate the different outputs I used the following code.

```
import tarfile
import csv

tar = tarfile.open("tar-file.tar.gz")

for member in tar.getmembers():
    f = tar.extractfile(member).read()
    print(member.name)
    print('Raw :', type(f))
    print(f)
    print()
    f = f.decode('ascii')
    print('ASCII:', type(f))
    print(f)
tar.close()
```

This produces the following output. (each csv contains the same data for this example).

```
./raw_data/csv-file1.csv
Raw : <class 'bytes'>
b'1079,SAMPLE_A,GROUP,001,,2017/02/15 22:57:30\n1041,SAMPLE_B,GROUP,023,,2017/02/15 22:57:26\n1077,SAMPLE_C,GROUP,005,,2017/02/15 22:57:31\n1079,SAMPLE_A,GROUP,128,,2017/02/15 22:57:38\n\n'

ASCII: <class 'str'>
1079,SAMPLE_A,GROUP,001,,2017/02/15 22:57:30
1041,SAMPLE_B,GROUP,023,,2017/02/15 22:57:26
1077,SAMPLE_C,GROUP,005,,2017/02/15 22:57:31
1079,SAMPLE_A,GROUP,128,,2017/02/15 22:57:38


./raw_data/csv-file2.csv
Raw : <class 'bytes'>
b'1079,SAMPLE_A,GROUP,001,,2017/02/15 22:57:30\n1041,SAMPLE_B,GROUP,023,,2017/02/15 22:57:26\n1077,SAMPLE_C,GROUP,005,,2017/02/15 22:57:31\n1079,SAMPLE_A,GROUP,128,,2017/02/15 22:57:38\n\n'

ASCII: <class 'str'>
1079,SAMPLE_A,GROUP,001,,2017/02/15 22:57:30
1041,SAMPLE_B,GROUP,023,,2017/02/15 22:57:26
1077,SAMPLE_C,GROUP,005,,2017/02/15 22:57:31
1079,SAMPLE_A,GROUP,128,,2017/02/15 22:57:38


./raw_data/csv-file3.csv
Raw : <class 'bytes'>
b'1079,SAMPLE_A,GROUP,001,,2017/02/15 22:57:30\n1041,SAMPLE_B,GROUP,023,,2017/02/15 22:57:26\n1077,SAMPLE_C,GROUP,005,,2017/02/15 22:57:31\n1079,SAMPLE_A,GROUP,128,,2017/02/15 22:57:38\n\n'

ASCII: <class 'str'>
1079,SAMPLE_A,GROUP,001,,2017/02/15 22:57:30
1041,SAMPLE_B,GROUP,023,,2017/02/15 22:57:26
1077,SAMPLE_C,GROUP,005,,2017/02/15 22:57:31
1079,SAMPLE_A,GROUP,128,,2017/02/15 22:57:38
```

How can I get the csv module to correctly read a file in memory provided by the tar module?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to use `io.StringIO()` to produce a file like object for the csv library to use. For example:

```
import tarfile
import csv
import io

with tarfile.open('input.rar') as tar:
    for member in tar:
        if member.isreg():      # Is it a regular file?
            print("{} - {} bytes".format(member.name, member.size))
            csv_file = io.StringIO(tar.extractfile(member).read().decode('ascii'))

            for row in csv.reader(csv_file):
                print(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

This question was raised again almost 3 years. Please note that in [python: use CSV reader with single file extracted from tarfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61069941/python-use-csv-reader-with-single-file-extracted-from-tarfile/61070117#61070117) a better solution could be found after short discussion:

```py
import tarfile
import csv
import io

with tarfile.open('input.rar') as tar:
    for member in tar:
        if member.isreg():      # Is it a regular file?
            print("{} - {} bytes".format(member.name, member.size))
            csv_file = io.TextIOWrapper(tar.extractfile(member), encoding="utf-8")

            for row in csv.reader(csv_file):
                print(row)
```

The TextIOWrapper will perform better for larger files because it does not need to consume a complete file at once. In contrast, when `tar.extractfile(member).read()` is executed, the complete member file is loaded into memory.