# python: use CSV reader with single file extracted from tarfile

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, tar

I am trying to use the [Python CSV reader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) to read a CSV file that I extract from a `.tar.gz` file using [Python's tarfile library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html).

I have this:

```
tarFile = tarfile.open(name=tarFileName, mode="r")
for file in tarFile.getmembers():
    tarredCSV = tarFile.extractfile(file)
    reader = csv.reader(tarredCSV)
    next(reader)    # skip header
    for row in reader:
        if row[3] not in CSVRows.values():
            CSVRows[row[3]] = row
```

All the files in the tar file are all CSVs.

I am getting an exception on the first file. I am getting this exception on the first `next` line:

```
_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)
```

How do I open said file (without extracting the file then opening it)?

Comment: Use some print statements to see what each iterator element looks like before moving on... maybe the usage of one of these functions is wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tarfile.extractfile` returns an `io.BufferedReader` object, a bytes stream, and yet `csv.reader` expects a text stream. You can use `io.TextIOWrapper` to convert the bytes stream to a text stream instead:

```py
import io

...

reader = csv.reader(io.TextIOWrapper(tarredCSV, encoding='utf-8'))
```

Comment: added your solution to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43466516/python3-working-with-csv-files-in-tar-files/61070394#61070394 as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a file-like object to `csv.reader`.

Probably the best solution, without having to consume a complete file at once is this approach (thanks to blhsing and damon for suggesting it):

```
import csv
import io
import tarfile

tarFile = tarfile.open(name=tarFileName, mode="r")
for file in tarFile.getmembers():
    csv_file = io.TextIOWrapper(tarFile.extractfile(file), encoding="utf-8")

    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    next(reader)    # skip header
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

Alternatively a possible solution from here: [Python3 working with csv files in tar files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43466516/python3-working-with-csv-files-in-tar-files) would be

```py
import csv
import io
import tarfile

tarFile = tarfile.open(name=tarFileName, mode="r")
for file in tarFile.getmembers():
    csv_file = io.StringIO(tarFile.extractfile(file).read().decode('utf-8'))

    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    next(reader)    # skip header
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

Here a `io.StringIO` object is used to make `csv.reader` happy. However, this might not scale well for larger files contained in the tar as each file is read in one single step.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer. I deleted my no-longer-relevant comment about memory efficiency :)

Comment: The comment is still relevant, it is just integrated into the post :) Thanks a lot!